# How to change the color of ball everytime it strike the wall, in processing? My code is as below

Tags: processing

This is the code I have. And in next step how can I make effect on the bouncing ball from keyboard keys.

```cpp
float circleX = 0;
float circleY = 0;

float xSpeed = 2.5;
float ySpeed = 2;

void setup() {
 size(500, 500); 
}

void draw() {
  background(0,200,0);

  circleX += xSpeed;
  if (circleX < 0 || circleX > width) {
    xSpeed *= -1;
  }

  circleY += ySpeed;
  if (circleY < 0 || circleY > height) {
    ySpeed *= -1;
  }

  ellipse(circleX, circleY, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: what is the question? title suggest color change on collision and the text implies keyboard handling so what is it?

Comment: oh actually it has two different questions. The first part(color change) is solved. Can you help with the keyboard handling part. Please.

Comment: not coding in processing ... so no as keyboard is environment dependent and color is already handled ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the color [`fill()`](https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html) each time the ball hits a wall:

```java
float circleX = 0;
float circleY = 0;
float xSpeed = 2.5;
float ySpeed = 2;

void setup() {
 size(500, 500); 
}

void changeColor() {
  fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
}

void draw() {
  background(0,200,0);

  circleX += xSpeed;
  if (circleX < 0 || circleX > width) {
    xSpeed *= -1;
    changeColor();
  }

  circleY += ySpeed;
  if (circleY < 0 || circleY > height) {
    ySpeed *= -1;
    changeColor();
  }

  ellipse(circleX, circleY, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please help with the keyboard handling part too?